# Disabling Alt+ArrowKey HotKey Mojave

Tags: keyboard, mojave, shortcut, remote-desktop

Is there anyway from disabling the hotkey that swipes between windows (alt+left or right arrow key)? I am using excel via remote desktop and when I use this shortcut Mac also reads the input and my window switches.

I have already looked under System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts and didn't see it listed under there

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). All the best with your question.

Comment: Are you sure it's alt/arrow? Default is Ctrl/arrow. Prefs are where you looked - prefs>keyboard>shortcuts>Mission Control.